# Проблема с float и и int в одном арифметическом выражении

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть вот такой код для вычисления нормы калорий в день для мужчин и женщин, но компилятор выдает мне вот такую ошибку:

```
cannot implicitly convert type float to int
```

Вот мой код :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Count
    {
        public int GetIndex( int growthC, int sex)
        {
            int index = growthC - 100 - ((growthC - 150) / sex);
            return index;
        }

        public float GetCaloriesM( float weightC, float growC, float yearsC)
        {
            int NomrmaCaloriesM = 88.36f + (13.4f *  weightC) + (4.8f * growC) - (5.7f * yearsC);
            return NormaCaloriesM;
        }

        public int GetCaloriesW(float weightC, float growC, float yearsC)
        {

            int NomrmaCaloriesW = 447.6 + (9.2 * weightC) + (3.1 * growC) - (4.3 * yearsC);
            return NormaCaloriesW;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в методах GetCaloriesM и GetCaloriesW.

Comment: Вы читали главы про типы в c# и про приведение типов?

Comment: ну и я надеюсь, вы понимаете правила целочисленного деления, я сейчас про это место: `(growthC - 150) / sex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор прав, вы пытаетесь записать в переменную типа int значение типа float, причем возвращаете вы из методов тоже float. Ну так и переменные объявите типа float:

```
float NomrmaCaloriesM = ...
```

и здесь:

```
float NomrmaCaloriesW = ...
```

Comment: Спасибо,понял в чем ошибка.

Comment: Ещё и опечатки лучше поправить. NormaCaloriesM does not exist in  the current context, а NomrmaCaloriesM -- существует.  И ещё во втором случае double to float не может скаститься автоматом.

Comment: Поправил,спасибо.